# Function + Switch statement in R: EXPR must be a length 1 vector

Tags: r

In the code below, the dataframe offshore_Sites already exists and contains at about 1000 records. I am building a function so I can re-use it for all the other dataframes I have.

The dataframes are obtained from SQL Server. At the moment I have only got the offshore_Sites one but the others will be produced in the same way.

The idea is to call this function, that has a switch statement inside and, depending on the dataframe, I will be performing different transformations. For the offshore_Sites one, I need to concatenate some of the fields, as in the example.

```
myStringConn <- "Driver=SQL Server;Server=SQL-SPATIAL;Database=AreasProt;Trusted_Connection=True;"
conn <- odbcDriverConnect(myStringConn)
offshore_Sites <- sqlQuery(conn, "select * from Offshore_Sites")

formatDataFrame <- function(dataframe) {
                              switch(dataframe, "offshore_Sites"  = {
                                offshore_sites <- as.data.table(offshore_Sites)
                                offshore_sites <- setnames(offshore_sites, 1:6, c("status","country","region","area","long","lat"))
                                offshore_sites <- unique(offshore_sites[, list(status,                                        
                                                                               country = paste(sort(unique(country)), collapse = ' & '),
                                                                               region = paste(sort(unique(region)), collapse = ' & '),
                                                                               area,
                                                                               long,
                                                                               lat), by = code])
                                })
                            }

formatDataFrame(offshore_Sites)
```

However, when I run this, I get the error:

> Error in switch(dataframe, offshore_Sites = { :
>         EXPR must be a length 1 vector

Does anyone understand what is happening?

Comment: It is better to provide a reproducible example.  One thing I noticed is the `setnames`, you are selecting 10 columns and naming 6.

Comment: Please include a sample of your `data.frame` (`dput(head(df, 30))`) in your question, and try to elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: To start, `switch` takes as it's first value an expression that resolves to a vector of length 1.  You are passing it a data frame that unlikely to have length 1, and is definitely not a vector.  Without knowing more about what is in the `offshore_Sites` data frame and what you want to do to it (and your other data frames), we won't be able to advise you on how to approach it.

Comment: The function you are calling is `switch(EXPR, ...)`.  R is expecting that your first argument, in this case `dataframe` is a vector of length 1.  In the `?switch` example, that is something like "mean" or "median" or "trimmed".  In the example, R then performs a certain function based on what is passed.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have added some more information. I need to pass a dataframe to both the function and the switch statement.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Can you provide a sample, for example `dput(head(offshore_Sites, 30))`, similar to nrussell's comment.  I am assuming `offshore_Sites` is a data frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had some inspiration today and I kind of spotted where the problem was. The function needs two variables, the dataframe name and the dataframe itself.

```
myStringConn <- "Driver=SQL Server;Server=SQL-SPATIAL;Database=AreasProt;Trusted_Connection=True;"
conn <- odbcDriverConnect(myStringConn)
offshore_Sites <- sqlQuery(conn, "select * from Offshore_Sites")

formatDataFrame <- function(dataframe, dataframeName) {
                            switch(dataframeName, "offshore_Sites"  = {
                                offshore_sites <- as.data.table(dataframe)
                                offshore_sites <- setnames(offshore_sites, 1:6, c("status","country","region","area","long","lat"))
                                offshore_sites <- unique(offshore_sites[, list(status,                                        
                                                                               country = paste(sort(unique(country)), collapse = ' & '),
                                                                               region = paste(sort(unique(region)), collapse = ' & '),
                                                                               area,
                                                                               long,
                                                                               lat), by = code])
                                })
                            }

formatDataFrame(offshore_Sites, "Offshore_Sites")
```

Thanks for all the comments :)